# How to disable element editor on custom element type?

Tags: plugin-development, control-panel, elementtype

I'm working on custom element type and I'd like to disable the editor modal at element index view that appears when you double-click on status icons/thumbnails in the title column. Any help?

Comment: Which one are you talking about, the modal or the one that opens from the links in the title column?

Comment: @carlcs I've edited my question. Hopefully, it's clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Element Editor HUD will only be available if your element model’s `isEditable()` method returns `true`. (It returns `false` by default.) Remove that method from your element model class and you should be good.